# How do I import data from a csv to SequelPro?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sequelpro

I have a small data file and I'd like to analyze it with SequelPro.

I have it connected to a MySQL server running on my computer.

When I try to import, the `Import` button is just greyed out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: I did, I put in research and couldn't find the answer. I'm not sure how to do an example for something like this. Certainly open to feedback. Thanks Sand.

Comment: if you have then you should have gone through all [this](https://www.google.lk/search?q=import+data+from+a+csv+to+Sequel+Pro&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjglciahLjWAhXollQKHdqPCDQQvwUIISgA&biw=1366&bih=615). Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. I've gone through those, still don't have an answer. I am able to get up to "CSV Import Field Mapping" but I don't know how to get past. The import button is stuck as grey for me.

Comment: You didn't understand my comment you have stated you problem but you have not shown what have been doing. If you already have written some peace of code then post it with your question it doesn't matter if the code is working or not.

Comment: It is not code. Are you familiar with SequelPro? If you are and you know how to import something, please do let me know. It's pretty frustrating to not know how to do a fairly simple task.

Comment: sorry for all the useless comments you got Sebastian, sadly this the lousy arrogant attitude of a lot of people on this site who would rather spend their time picking holes in people's questions and antagonising them rather and providing help.

How ironic that the people leaving the comments failed to read your question properly and didn't grasp the fact that you are not doing this with code. I'm glad to see you finally got the answer, that you simply need to create a table first. Good luck.

Comment: I think the real problem is that this question belongs on SuperUser ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a table first. Only then will the import button become selectable.

Answer (score 5):

Enter a table name in the "Name" text box in the upper right hand corner.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's not clear from the UX you have to fill out the "Name:" field - but it solved the problem. Thanks @Mike!

Comment: I agree with this answer. Using this method table columns are auto-created based on CSV headers.

Answer (score 0):

This is very straight forward to do. Hover your mouse at the top of your screen. This would display a menu. click on file and click on import... Hope this helps